# Twitter4J AccessToken Generation

Tags: java, twitter4j, access-token

I am trying to create instance of AccessToken but its raising exception message. I have two ways to generate the AccessToken. My workflow is that on android machine I authenticate the user using Oauth and then I get the accessKey, and accessSecret. I transfer those two strings to server using REST. I do following on server to get back AccessToken.

`AccessToken token = new AccessToken(accessToken, accessSecret);`

But above code is generating exeption that "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid access token format." 
When I do the following:

```
twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(); 
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET); 
AccessToken aToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(accessToken, accessSecret);
```

It gives following twitter exception:

The screen name / password combination seems to be invalid.Relevant discussions can be on the Internet at:......

Finally, I also used following code:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder(); 
cb.setDebugEnabled(true) .setOAuthConsumerKey(twitterKey)
.setOAuthConsumerSecret(twitterSecret) 
.setOAuthAccessToken(twitter.getAccessToken())
.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(twitter.getSecretToken()); 
TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build()); 
twitter4j.Twitter t4jTwitter = tf.getInstance();
```

It gives same invalid format exception.

So my question is that "is this a potential bug??" and Can I create AccessToken instance when I already have accessKey and accessSecret strings??

Thank you very much for the prompt reply.

Irfan Mirza

Comment: Are you sure you have the access token or request token?

Comment: @Buhake Sindi did you get any solution for this ? please guide i am also stuck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure accessToken and accessSecret contain OK values? It really could be caused by some omission that would make those empty or something.

Comment: Yes those two strings are populated... for example the accesstoken value i get is the following: R4djAteHEEParteG4hOzvdGngQ94kNjLcwFKlQWBN0